# Is accessing a value from params hash directly via a key insecure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I just had a debate with a coworker, we have a nested route:

```
/foo/:foo_id/bar/:id(.:format)
```

In the controller, I was doing this:

```
Foo.find(params[:foo_id])
```

He said I should be getting foo_id via strong params, which I disagreed with. I thought strong params is to ensure an array within params does not contain keys you don't specify, and does nothing to the values themselves.

Who is right?

Edit, and in the case of updating a record, is the below right or wrong? So, getting the id itself via params, then using strong params for the attribute array.

```
Foo.find(params[:foo_id]).update(foo_params)

def foo_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:attr_one, :attr_two, :attr_three)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. In a `GET` request you don't need to use strong params, since you are just querying the database.

You have to be careful when creating/updating records, like in this case:

```
Foo.create(params[:foo]) # Someone could just pass admin:true into the params
```

Edit:

The case of updating is fine too. When you're trying to find a record by the key `:foo_id` it doesn't matter if there are any extra keys in the params hash. Strong params are required when doing mass asignment (calling `update` in this case)

Comment: Thanks for your input. That is what I thought too. I did just update the question, is it is the same for the update in the way I outlined above?

Comment: You're weilcome @RichardAE! edited the answer for your second case